# An ifelse statement based on grepl

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
address <- c("Weg", "Laan", "Molenweg")
b <- seq(1:3)
df <- data.frame(address, b)
```

What I would like to do  now I see whether address contains a certain word and then label a column. So like this:

```
df_weg <- df$address
x <- c("weg")
df$test <- ifelse(grepl(x, df_weg), 1, 0)
```

This works fine but im looking for a way to label an item as 0/1 when the word is in a list. So it should work like this:

```
x <- c("weg", "laan")
df$test <- ifelse(grepl(x, df_weg), 1, 0)
```

But  when I try this I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(x, df_weg) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any thougts on how i can get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following expression:

```
x <- "weg|laan" # or paste(c("weg", "laan"), collapse="|")
df$test <- ifelse(grepl(x, df_weg), 1, 0)
```

`|` in a `regex` means "or"

As a more direct way, thanks to @DavidArenburg, as you need a 0/1 output, you can just convert the logical result of `grepl` to integer:

```
as.integer(grepl("weg|laan", df_weg))
```

or, if you want to do codegolfing (but less good pratice):

```
+grepl("weg|laan", df_weg)
```

Comment: Can't we just `as.integer(grepl("weg|laan", df_weg))`? Or the `+` unary operator in order to piss off Konrad?

Comment: @David It’s nice to think that I take it personally. But really I’m just complaining about bad code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that instant response of your almost made fall of the chair. Man, you re awesome.

Comment: On a more serious note, the above — like the question — doesn’t search for a *word*, it searches for arbitrary substrings. This may lead to some surprises. So, if searching for words is intended, one should use word boundary markers in the pattern: `'\\b(weg|laan)\\b'`.

Comment: @Konrad, I guess, except if `weg` is for `weg` and `molenweg`... there may be case problem also (`weg` will match `molenweg` but not `Weg`, as written in the Q, not sure it's on purpose...)